# How to return the list which corresponds to a value in a list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

Let's say I have this list here:

`lista = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", 2, 3], ["a", 4, 5], ["f", "g", "h"]]`

If I were to find `"a"` in `lista`, would it be possible to return the lists that `"a"` appears in? If so, how would I go about doing it.

```
>>> findallinlistoflists(a)
["a", "b", "c"]
["a", 2, 3]
["a", 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear how you picked `"a"`, but once chosen you can do

```
[L for L in lista if "a" in L]
```

Comment: Yep. I just want to find if it exists in the list. This is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
def find(a,lista):
    containingLists = []
    for i in lista:
        for j in i:
            if(j==a):
                containingLists.append(i);
                break
    return containingLists
```